# Rails meta programming and performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

Rails conventions force framework and gem writers to make extensive use of reflection/meta programming. I've always assumed meta programming to be less efficient, and with the trend of using an ever growing number of gems, the question is - whats the PERFORMANCE impact?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Rails conventions. Lots of things are absolutely easier to solve (and later maintain) using metaprogramming.

Comment: Its related to conventions because most methods are handled through wildcarding (take a look at activerecord, actionpack to name a few). While with frameworks/languages where configuration is the rule, rarely do frameworks use method reflection eg J2EE

Comment: Java and Ruby are so different that every possible comparison fails long before you come to web frameworks. BTW, "metaprogramming" is such a broad term (as @shingara already mentioned). Did you have `method_missing` in mind mostly?

Comment: Yes, i know they're different and the Java example was just to make it obvious as to what I mean by metaprogramming needs that stem from convention over configuration philosophy of rails. method_missing is one, introspection such as respond_to?, class etc

Answer (score 3):

Programmer productivity >> Software Performance (usually)

Really, don't worry about this... in practice correct algorithms, correct architecture, correct database model and so on are much more important than pure language performance...

X effort not spent on fighting the language (java xml hell, c compilation) is effort spent on designing better algorithms, UX which results in better and more user friendlier application

Comment: While your statement holds true for the major chunk of web apps out there (most apps get no where close to what may be considered high traffic in their lifetime), the concern I have is that does excessive reflection in rails makes it unsuitable for extremely high traffic websites

Comment: the last sentence sounds loaded ie "unsuitable for extremely high traffic websites". A better statement would be if there are pitfalls associated with reflection that we need to start letting go once we need to eke out performance, similar to using SQL queries at times rather than just relying on ORM

Answer (score 0):

Really depend what kind of metaprogramming. Some are no impact performance during the runtime. Just a little slow in starting.

Do benchmark on your case and see what kind of impact there are.